System Breack down on "system Monitor"
I just upgraded the pc RAM to 16 GB (it's a DELL PRECISION T 1500, 8 × Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz): The memory shown by the system is 7,7 GiB di RAM. Trying to visualize Monitor system inf. the system broke-down three times, i.e. just jammed! ( I had to take the power off).
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Test the Memory

Remove Both Sticks
Put the new stick you bought in the slot where the old memory resided.
Reboot the machine, and go to the system firmware/BIOS settings.
On the main screen/first page, the total memory count should be 8,192
Shutdown
Put the old stick that you replaced in the other memory slot (Leave the new one in the old one's slot)
Repeat Step 3 and see if the number is 16,384

If Step 7 still reads 8,192 you have a bad DIMM slot.  If it reads 16,384 proceed to booting Ubuntu and leave the machine on for at least an hour to test stability
Reasoning

Putting the new stick in the old DIMM slot tests the new stick.
Putting the used stick in the DIMM that was unused tests the DIMM Slot itself

Going Further
If the tests above don't return the expected results, the OP is stuck with 2 possible causes:

The new memory you bought is bad, or you put it in the slot backwards.
The unused slot is either old and not functioning, or you've caused a breakage because of 1, i.e., it was inserted into the slot backwards.

